# Get Large and Small for every group where a column value is equal and return a 3rd column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large set of data (approx. 500,000 rows) with water level information.  There are 3 columns.

```
A: the water level (i.e. 0.7)
B: the date (i.e. 03/01/16)
C: the time (i.e 6:06:00)
```

I need to get the 2 largest and 2 smallest values from A for every day B and return A & C.

So basically for all the rows where the date is equal find the largest and smaller tell me those values and give me the associated time.

Here is a bit of data:

2.730    |    03/04/16    |    3:54:00
2.734    |    03/04/16    |   3:36:00
2.735    |   03/04/16    |   3:48:00
2.736    |   03/04/16    |   3:42:00
0.046    |   03/05/16    |   10:30:00
0.047    |   03/05/16    |   10:36:00
0.048    |   03/05/16    |   10:24:00
0.050    |   03/05/16    |   10:42:00
0.052    |   03/05/16    |   10:18:00
0.056    |   03/05/16    |   10:48:00

There are approximately 240 rows for every day for 5 years.  In the end I want a table with just the highs and lows from every day with the time.

I have tried various solutions like

> =LARGE(A2:A241,1)

on column A and

> =VLOOKUP(F2,A2:C241,2,FALSE)

to grab the associated data, but I have no idea how to do it for multiple days without manually selecting each day and doing the formula 1826 times.  Please Help.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you want the results formatted (laid out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such a large data set you want to avoid array formulas, so an approach that limits the lookup range for a Small() or Large() is better.

Consider the screenshot and the results of the formulas. I entered the first date in E2 and used the fill handle to drag down and auto-increment. My dates display in DMY order.

[image]

The formulas are

F2 `=LARGE(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0)):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,1)),1)`

G2 `=LARGE(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0)):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,1)),2)`

H2 `=SMALL(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0)):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,1)),1)`

I2 `=SMALL(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0)):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,1)),2)`

.... copied down. This approach requires that the data is sorted ascending by the dates in column B.

To return the matching value from column C, wrap the formula in an Index on column C with a Match on column A, for example the time for the 2nd Smallest is

```
=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(SMALL(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0)):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,1)),2),$A:$A,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

In E2 the only Array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$10,MATCH(0,IF(COUNTIF($E$1:$E1,$B$1:$B$10)=0,0,1),0)),"")
```

This one formula must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

In F2:

```
=IF(E2<>"",AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$1:$A$10/($B$1:$B$10=E2),1),"")
```

In G2:

```
=IF(E2<>"",INDEX($C$1:$C$10,MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$1:$A$10/($B$1:$B$10=E2),1),$A$1:$A$10,0)),"")
```

In H2:

```
=IF(E2<>"",AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$1:$A$10/($B$1:$B$10=E2),1),"")
```

In I2:

```
=IF(E2<>"",INDEX($C$1:$C$10,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$1:$A$10/($B$1:$B$10=E2),1),$A$1:$A$10,0)),"")
```

Then copy down.  The aggregate function was introduced in 2010.

Then copy the formula down as far as needed.  In the picture the formulas are copied down to row 15.

This method does not care if the list is ordered or not.

If it is ordered than I believe that @teylyn answer is a quicker compute.

Comment: The smallest value for 3/5 is 0.046 at 10:30, not 0.047 at 10:36. The result of the Aggregate approach does not seem to be correct.

Comment: I think you need just a `1` instead of `Row(1:1)`, otherwise it will return the 2nd, 3rd, etc smallest upon copying down.

Comment: @teylyn, yup I overthought it I am fixing it now, thank you for the catch

Comment: Sorry, just one more thought: you are dividing one range by another range. How will that behave with half a million rows in the data set? That's an awful lot of calculation. I think that the Index approach will calculate faster.

Comment: I created a setup that compares the performance of the two approaches. I posted it in a new answer. Check it out.

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you clarify the source for your statement that AGGREGATE with an initial parameter of 15 is faster than the equivalent MIN/IF CSE set-up? I was led to believe that the latter was, if anything, a fraction more efficient than the former, though I can't honestly believe that there's much difference at all between the two.

Comment: @XORLX you are probably correct, I have never done an actual test along the lines that Teylyn did, It may be just me wanting and expecting it to be that is coloring my perception.  I have erased the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this as another answer, not trying to provide a solution to the question, but because I want to show my findings about the calculation speed comparison between the Index and the Aggregate approaches provided in previous answers.

Setup:

Excel "data" sheet with 500,000 rows of data, columns "value", "date", "time"
Each date is represented multiple times. The data ranges from 1/Jan/2000 to  5/Apr/2014. There are 98 entries for each day.

On another sheet Column E has the 5209 dates, one date per row. Two different formulas are used in columns F and G to find the largest value for each date in the "data" sheet.

Column H compares the output of the two formulas and cell K1 counts the differences in the results. There is no difference. Both formulas provide exactly the same result.

The sheet has 5209 rows with formulas. Each of these formulas evaluates 500,000 rows of data.

The formula in the "Index" columns is

```
=LARGE(INDEX(data!$A:$A,MATCH($E3,data!$B:$B,0)):INDEX(data!$A:$A,MATCH($E3,data!$B:$B,1)),1)
```

Note: This approach depends on the source data to be sorted ascending by the date column. Chances are that the data is generated by some monitoring system that will put one reading after the other. Unless there is human or programmatic intervention, I will assume that the data is sorted by date.

The formula in the "Aggregate" column is

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,data!$A$2:$A$500000/(data!$B$2:$B$500000=E2),1)
```

**The goal** is to work out which formula is more efficient, i.e. calculates faster. I am using code written by [Charles Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88173/charles-williams), who specializes in performance of formulas and VBA. I have used his Range Timer, as published in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700515.aspx).

Here is a screenshot of my setup:

[image]

I selected the column with the Index formula and ran the timer three times. The results were in the range of 19 seconds.

[image]

I then selected the column with the Aggregate formula and ran the timer. The first pass took 411 seconds, which is 6:52 minutes. The second pass took 425 seconds (7:05 mins).

[image]

I did not run a third pass on the Aggregate formula results, because my laptop fan was going into overdrive and getting quite hysterical and high-pitched.

**Why am I posting this?**

I would like to draw attention to a few things:

- data samples in questions often contain only a few rows of data
- hence, formulas suggested here are often only tested on a small data sample, but when used in the real environment may not perform as well as expected.
- the suggested Index formula looks complicated and is quite a mouthful. The suggested Aggregate formula is much shorter and looks much neater, BUT, the formula with Index performs a LOT better than the formula with Aggregate. Hence: **a shorter formula does not always result in a faster calculation**

My sample file can be accessed [here](http://1drv.ms/20KSffT), if you want to give it a spin. Just be aware that it's around 20 MB, since it has so much data. To run the macro, select a range and click the blue button.

Comment: Completely agree, though of course such an alternative is only available if we can make use of data in strictly ascending (or descending) order, which perhaps should be made explicit in the post so that readers are aware of the limitations on this improved set-up.

Comment: @XORLX yes, the Index approach requires the data to be sorted. I pointed that out in my answer with the Index approach. I will edit this answer to level the playing field.

Comment: fwiw, the same range limiting on the sorted data could be applied to the AGGREGATE formula  as well. When this is added, the times become pretty much identical.

Comment: @Jeeped, not sure I understand your comment. The data is sorted by date in my sample file. Do you have a trick up your sleeve  that makes AGGREGATE work faster in this scenario?

Comment: For the `LARGE(INDEX...` it would be `=AGGREGATE(14, 6, INDEX(A:A, MATCH($E2,B:B, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH($E2,B:B)), 1)` on the sorted data. It's virtually identical to the LARGE version. My point was that apples must be compared with apples. If the AGGREGATE is going to be tested on half-a-million rows with criteria, then the LARGE(INDEX(... should have been as well.