# 2 recent rates for llisted Product_IDs corresponding to recent occurances

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have following sample data. I want to find rates corresponding to two recent dates for Product_IDs.

```
    A         B       C          E         F             G        H               I
Trnx_Date   Prod_ID Rate        Pro_ID  Recent_dt1  Recent_dt2  RateRecent_dt1 RateRecent_dt2
17-07-2020  917     1040        917    04-08-2020   04-08-2020  1052           1052
20-07-2020  917     1040        920    04-08-2020   22-07-2020  1052           2115.01
21-07-2020  917     1040        114    20-07-2020   17-07-2020  1040           1040
23-07-2020  917     1045                        
29-07-2020  917     1048.5                      
30-07-2020  917     1058                        
31-07-2020  917     1050        Results Desired             
03-08-2020  917     1050        Pro_ID  Recent_dt1  Recent_dt2  RateRecent_dt1  RateRecent_dt2        
04-08-2020  917     1052        917     04-08-2020  03-08-2020  1052            1050
20-07-2020  920     2110        920     04-08-2020  22-07-2020  2120            2115.01
21-07-2020  920     2112        114     20-07-2020  17-07-2020  1040            1040
22-07-2020  920     2115.01                     
04-08-2020  920     2120                        
17-07-2020  114     1958.1                      
20-07-2020  114     1958.1
```

Similiar question has been asked here as per following reference.
[Get Large and Small for every group where a column value is equal and return a 3rd column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215590/get-large-and-small-for-every-group-where-a-column-value-is-equal-and-return-a-3/35215911#35215911)

I have used following formulas in
`[F2]`

```
=LARGE(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($E2,B:B,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH($E2,B:B,1)),1)
```

in `[G2]`

```
 =LARGE(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($E2,B:B,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH($E2,B:B,1)),2)
```

in `[H2]`

```
 =INDEX(C:C,MATCH(LARGE(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($E2,B:B,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH($E2,B:B,1)),1),A:A,0))
```

in `[I2]`

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(LARGE(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($E2,B:B,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH($E2,B:B,1)),2),A:A,0))
```

I am not getting desired results using these formulas and requires suitable modification to suit to my data structure. Though I have sorted data on Prod_ID and Trnx_Date , whether modification can work on unsorted data. Please help in adjusting these formulas suitably. I am open to `VBA` solution also.

Comment: @braX I have deleted duplicate question. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: @RichieV Can you point to a question answered here which shows your poposed idea to split the F2 formula into steps, first return the start and end rows (i.e. 2 & 10) on two different columns, then use OFFSET formula to get a dynamic range for all your other formulas. However I would pefer some approach without helper columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula as below

[image]

Formula is G2

```
=MAX(IF(  SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$16=F2,$A$2:$A$16,9999999),1)  =  $A$2:$A$16, IF(  $B$2:$B$16=F2, $C$2:$C$16, 0)))
```

Formula in H2

```
=MAX(IF(  SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$16=F2,$A$2:$A$16,9999999),2)  =  $A$2:$A$16, IF(  $B$2:$B$16=F2, $C$2:$C$16, 0)))
```

Comment: Your formula is showing results which are not matching with my desired results as shown in my post. For 917 it should be 1052 and 1050.

Comment: I have used small, you can use large, and change 999999 to 0. =MAX(IF(  LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$16=F2,$A$2:$A$16,0),1)  =  $A$2:$A$16, IF(  $B$2:$B$16=F2, $C$2:$C$16, 0)))

Comment: Your both approaches are giving result as `0`

Comment: its an array formula, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: Pleasefirst tryout at your end. I have entered it as an array formula already.

Comment: it is possible that the dates you have are not dates, check that as well, maybe they are entered as strings

Comment: please wait I am retrying your formula by changing correct references. My prod_id was in `E `which you have changed to `F`